# Displaying custom fields on a lightbox gallery

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I want to replicate this gallery:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

But instead of the static pictures, i need it to display the contents of my "gallery" field in Advanced Custom fields.

This is my code:

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('extra_photos');

if( $images ): ?>
<div class="row2">
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
<div class="column2">
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow2">
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>    


<!-- Images used to open the lightbox -->

</div>

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal2">
  <span class="close2 cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content2">

    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext2">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" style="width:100%">
    </div>


    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <!-- Caption text -->
    <div class="caption-container2">
      <p id="caption2"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Thumbnail image controls -->
    <div class="column2">
      <img class="demo2" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature">
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It only displays the first image of the gallery.

You can see it in action here:

http://electives-abroad.org/hospital-internships-and-electives-at-mkoani-hospital-on-pemba-island/

How can i solve it?

*UPDATE*

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>
// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "block";
}

// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo2");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption2");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem you're having is the onclick() function. It's the same in each item. SRC is fine, but when you click on the image it always redirects to the same one.

Comment: Yeah, i was wondering the same. 

So how can i fix this?

onclick="currentSlide(1)"

Comment: I'm not a magician haha. Please, upload the javascript

Comment: Done. It's on the question now.

Comment: OK, javascript is not the problem. Apparently is the PHP. Just check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck5PI.png. You print `$image['url']` in `mySlides2`. You always get the same URL.